# How to convert tf2 model so it will run on tflite interpreter

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

**Background:**
I am trying to convert the tf2 model for SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320 (for example) from the official tf zoo. The model should run eventually on raspberry pi, so I would like it to run on the tflite interpreter (without full tf). The docs imply that ssd model conversion is supported.

**Whats happening:**
the process is detailed in [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P7T-ghA68mrNIRXjDPc_A59-lLxfq5yw?usp=sharing). It is failing with the error:

```
ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc(callsite(callsite("Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/SortByField_1/Size@__inference___call___23519" at "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper_25508") at "StatefulPartitionedCall")): 'tf.Size' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
<unknown>:0: note: loc("StatefulPartitionedCall"): called from
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': Ops that can be supported by the flex runtime (enabled via setting the -emit-select-tf-ops flag):
    tf.Size {device = ""}
```

if I add the flag tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS, it works but wont run on the rpi, as it does not have the ops.

Can this be done? Has anyone succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TF.Size is not natively supported on TFLite you can use TF Select mode which fallbacks to TF for the missing op, which during conversion is enabled using "SELECT_TF_OPS" that you tried.
When you run inference you will need to use Interpreter which have Select ops linked.
See the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#run_inference) on running inference.

Comment: This means I will have to have tf installed, no? In this instance, on the rpi, it is not a great option.

Comment: Ah i see... Ouch, compiling... I'll check if there is a precompiled Binary somewhere. Thank you

Comment: If you're using python, you can just install the pip package. If java there are precompiled AAR.
Check the link above.

Comment: unfortunately not on rpi. there is a specific build for it and it does not have the selected ops installed

Comment: File a github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new/choose) for the team